# How to import a Json file into a collection of MongoDB 6.0?

Tags: json, mongodb

I am new in MongoDB. I don't know how to insert a json file in to a collection in MongoDB 6.0.
I tried this in windows cmd:
mongoimport --uri mongodb://localhost:27017/ --collection  --type json --file

But I was facing this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBZhN.png)

I was trying to follow this:
[Json to MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8L96.png)

source: https://www.mongodb.com/compatibility/json-to-mongodb

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [mongoimport Examples](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/#examples)

Would be like this:

```
mongoimport --uri="mongodb://localhost:27017" --collection=xyz --type=json --file="c:\Temp\abcd.json"
```